# How to determine a template parameter at runtime in c++

Tags: c++, templates, threadpool

I define a `ThreadPool`class, and it has a memeber: `std::array<Worker, ThreadNum> Workerlist`.
The code is as follows:

```
#ifndef THREADPOOL_H
#define THREADPOOL_H
#include <pthread.h>
#include <memory>
#include "Worker.h"
#include <vector>
#include <array>
const int MAX_THREAD_NUM = 16;

class ThreadPool
{
private:
    const unsigned int                                  ThreadNum;
    std::shared_ptr<EventLoop>                          MainLoop;
    std::array<std::shared_ptr<Worker>, ThreadNum>      WorkerList;
    std::array<std::shared_ptr<EventLoop>, ThreadNum>   EventLoopList;
    unsigned int                                        NextLoopIndex;
    
public:
    ThreadPool(std::shared_ptr<EventLoop> loop, int threadNum = 12);
    ~ThreadPool();

    void                        RunThreadPool();
    std::shared_ptr<EventLoop>  GetNextEventLoop();
}
#endif
```

ThreadPool.cpp

```
ThreadPool::ThreadPool(std::shared_ptr<EventLoop> loop, int threadNum): MainLoop(loop), ThreadNum(threadNum), NextLoopIndex(0)
{
    if (ThreadNum<=0 || ThreadNum> MAX_THREADS)
    {
        LOG << "The num of threads is out of range.\n";
    }
}

ThreadPool::~ThreadPool() {}

void ThreadPool::RunThreadPool()
{
    WorkerList.fill(std::make_shared<Worker>());
    for (auto i = 0; i < ThreadNum; i++)
    {
        EventLoopList.at(i) = WorkerList.at(i)->ReturnEventLoopPtr();
    }
}

std::shared_ptr<EventLoop> ThreadPool::GetNextEventLoop()
{
    if (!EventLoopList.empty())
    {
        std::shared_ptr<EventLoop> nextLoop = EventLoopList[NextLoopIndex];
        NextLoopIndex = (NextLoopIndex + 1) % ThreadNum;
        return nextLoop;
    }
    return;
}
```

The error message is:

```
invalid use of data member ThreadPool::ThreadNum
```

In my opinion, the template parameter `ThreadNum` should be a constant, but now I need to infer its value when the class is constructed. Any solutions? Thank you very much.

Comment: The value of `ThreadNum` is determined at runtime by the constructor, but the array size must be a compile-time constant. You'll need to use something that allows run-time size, such as a `std::vector`.

Comment: `ThreadNum` is not a template parameter. It's a `const unsigned int` member of the class `ThreadPool`. Using it to specify the type of your arrays doesn't really do anything. You still need to give it a value at compile-time. It looks like you want `ThreadPool` to be a template class and `ThreadNum` a template parameter.